# Cloudflare is redirecting my request from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudflare

I have a website hosted on AWS with different containers for the frontend (react) and backend (fastapi). I am using Cloudflare and it seems that for a single request, it is being redirected to  HTTP from HTTPS context and I am getting a 307 error. All the other requests are working properly and I am using the same method to handle all the requests.

[image: The location field is showing HTTP, looks like it's from CF]

It's working locally and I see no issues with the code. I can share the code if needed.

Comment: What do the logs show? Does the request hit any of your infrastructure in AWS?

Comment: It does not reach the backend at all

Comment: Do you have any Cloudflare page rules setup that perform redirects? That's the only thing I can think of in Cloudflare that may be doing this. Otherwise do you have a load balancer or something on AWS? Are you sure it isn't something in your AWS stack that is issuing the redirect?